# Implementing event in base of a object

Tags: c#, events

Ive implemented an event in a object like this:

```
public class BaseObject
{
    public delegate void NavigateHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public virtual event NavigateHandler Navigate;
```

A child og that base tries to invoke it:

```
public class ChildObject : BaseObject
{
    private void DoNavigate()
    {
        Navigate(null, null);
```

This part above is broken, VS2012 tells me that I cant use `Navigate` in that manner.

However, it works fine to "hook" on that event if I instansiate a object of `ChildObject`:

```
ChildObject obj = new ChildObject();
obj.Navigate += foo_Navigate;
```

Where did I go wrong? I want to trigger that navigate event in the `DoNavigate` method.

Comment: Use `EventHandler` instead of making your own delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only allow to invoke events from within the class that defines it.

If you want to allow sub-classes to fire the event then create a `protected` method (by convention it would be called `OnNavigate`) that fires the event and that can be accessed from implementing classes.